# Find css selector by href value in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to find a link by href value using a css selector? I have a link with a nested span tag so I cannot find by linktext. I'm trying to find the href value but getting a syntax error.

```
WebElement storeElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href=/site/olspage.jsp?id=cat12090&amp;type=page&amp;rdct=n" data-lid="hdr_stl"]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible. try this

```
a[href^='href=/site/olspage.jsp?id=cat12090']
```

with `^` I am doing partial search and it means *start-with*

Answer (score 0):

For sure, it didn't works. You have to be careful with `double quotes ""`. You are opening and closing the css selector all the time. You have to put a `\` before a double quote to treat double quotes like a special character. You will have to put them like this:

```
WebElement storeElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href=/site/olspage.jsp?id=cat12090&amp;type=page&amp;rdct=n\" data-lid=\"hdr_stl\"]"));
```

Please let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Hi, I think I'm on a better track but now webdriver is not clicking my link.

WebElement storeElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href=\"/site/olspage.jsp?id=cat12090&amp;type=page&amp;rdct=n\"]"));
  storeElement.click();

Comment: @geekchick Where are you trying to retrieve this link? Can you put the `url` of the site in which there is this link? Maybe the reference it's wrong.